# GA4 Session_starts not triggering

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I have a challenge with a session starts not triggering in GA4, it effects about 40k sessions in the last month, these sessions are real visits because i can see purchases from them but page views, engagement rates and source/medium reporting is being affected. Can anyone suggest what may be causing this? or a solution i can use in Bigquery so the metrics are not impacted by this but I don't miss out the sales?

I do not have any Apps linked to my website,
the problem affect multiple pages and domains.
[image]

Comment: Are you sending your purchase events using measurement protocols?

Comment: @aliizadi, yes i am, the sales are real because i can see them in my CRM. I am also getting video views and visitors without a session_start appearing on a second page.

Comment: this issue is caused by not sending ga_session_id through the measurement protocol. Refer to point 5 in this article: https://medium.com/@aliiz/navigating-measurement-protocol-challenges-and-eliminating-not-set-issues-in-ga4-a-technical-7f01863649d6